# Region of convergence of complex series $\sum \frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

I am looking for region of convergence of the complex series $\sum\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}.$ For $|z|>1$ it’s not convergent as $nth$ doesn’t tends to zero . For me it’s seems that it doesn’t convergent for $|z|=1$. Please suggest me for the region $|z|\leq 1$. Thanks

Comment: NB: the series *cannot* in general converge for $|z|=1$, since it is simply undefined for $z=1$.

Comment: But defined for other points of unit circle

Comment: Ohh yes nth power makes it undefined

Comment: So only remaining case is $|z|<1$ ....

Comment: Well, it is undefined on a dense subset of the unit circle (all roots of unity of any power). This doesn't affect radius of convergence, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $|z|=1$ and $z^{n} \neq 1$ for any $n$ (so that the series is defined) then $|\frac {z^{n}} {1-z^{n}}|=\frac 1 {|1-z^{n}|}$ which does not tend to $0$, so the series is not convergent. If $|z|<1$ then $|\frac {z^{n}} {1-z^{n}}|\leq \frac {|z|^{n}} {1-|z|^{n}}$ and $1-|z|^{n} \geq \frac 1 2$ for $n$ sufficiently large. By comparison with $\sum z^{n}$ the series is convergent for $|z| <1$.

Comment: Thanks sir .....